# Русификация админской панели в django

Tags: django, django-admin

Некоторые статьи на русском нашел, но все достаточно старые. Подскажите, как это лучше реализовать на новых версиях?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Введение:

Наиболее каноничным, с точки зрения Django и разработки в целом, будет вариант хранения переводов в отдельном файле. Для решения этой задачи, Django предоставляет несколько [методов](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.translation), основные из которых:

- [`ugettext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.ugettext) - Переводит переданную строку
- [`ugettext_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.ugettext_lazy) - [Ленивая](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translations) версия предыдущей функции.

Обычно, эти функции импортируются как `_`:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

Достаточно просто обернуть строку вызовом данной функции, чтобы Django перевел ее в соответствии с таблицами перевода:

```
output = _("Welcome to my site.")
```

### Как генерировать переводы:

Перед тем, как создавать файлы переводов, необходимо указать, где они будут расположены. Это можно сделать, указав переменную [`LOCALE_PATHS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations). Пример из документации:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/home/www/project/common_files/locale',
    '/var/local/translations/locale',
)
```

Пример моего конфига:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'translations', 'locale'),
)
```

Кроме того, необходимо указать переменную [`LANGUAGE_CODE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-LANGUAGE_CODE):

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'
```

Для того, чтобы сгенерировать файл переводов, необходимо выполнить команду [`makemessages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#makemessages)

```
./manage.py makemessages -a
```

Флаг `-a` указывает, что необходимо обновить переводы для всех языков.

После выполнения этой команды, необходимо выполнить [`compilemessages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#compilemessages), которая скомпилирует все переводы в файлы с расширением `*.mo`:

```
./manage.py compilemessages
```

После этого, все переводы подхватятся автоматически.

Стоит отметить, что если для какой-либо строки не указан перевод, то будет выведен оригинал (в данном примере, пока Вы не укажате перевод для `"Welcome to my site."`, пользователю будет отображаться англоязычный вариант)

Answer (score 3):

в **settings.py**:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'
```

А также используйте **Meta** в моделях:

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Вопрос'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Вопросы'
```

Comment: А поля как перевести?

Comment: а ещё мне даёт такую ошибку: The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: ������. В начале документа стоит `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: @ashalbulk поля переводятся очень просто - `models.BooleanField('Переведено')`, а если используете FK или M2M, то `verbose_name='Что-нибудь'`. Вначале должно быть `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`, если у Вас Python 2. Если получаете ошибку, значит, что-то сделали не правильно, читайте логи

Comment: да, Ваш способ сработал, Я просто нашел где-то на просторах интернетов способ с .po и там использовалась такая строка `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`.  Пытался использовать `_('Вопрос')`. Попробовал без фун-ии и не выдало ошибок, спасибо. Но хотелось бы разобраться в варианте с ".po". Поможете? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936279/how-to-translate-plurals-of-a-model-in-the-django-admin)  Прошелся по этому посту, всё сделал и чуть-чуть больше. Но, как и у автора у меня не завелось, хотя ошибок нет.

Comment: @ashalbulk вы задаете 2 вопроса, изначально вопрос был про "русификацию", а теперь вы спрашиваете про интернационализацию. А это уже совсем другая тема, создайте новый вопрос и закройте этот, если мои инструкции помогли

Comment: @Levi Не совсем так. Меня не интересует интернационализация. Меня интересует централизованная руссификация. Все переводы в одном файле. Вариант который Вы предложили работает, но он больше похож на костыль.